# Geometric construction of a point, given three other points

Tags: geometry

Given three points $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in the plane ($\Bbb R^2$), what is the point (or points) $P$ for which the sum of the distances from it to the three given points is minimal?  In other words, what point(s) $P$ minimizes the function of $P$ $$|x_1-P|+ |x_2-P|+|x_3-P|?$$

I'm interested in geometrically constructing $P$, not simply in an expression for $P$.  For example, if the question was to find a $P$ which minimizes the sum of the squares of the distances, than it turns out that the answer would be "the baricenter", which can be constructed as the intersection point of the medians of the triangle spanned by $x_1,x_2,x_3$.  Is there also a simple way to construct a $P$ which minimizes the sum of the distances?

Comment: look up fermat-torricelli point

Comment: That's right. I didn't know this point.